# Visual Studio Code - Source control: add .gitignore exception

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSC in a project that has a main root folder with some files and other folders with specific applications.

The main folder has its own git with a .gitignore directive to exclude all subfolder. Each subfolder has its own git.

I suppose that VSC uses .gitignore to activate Source control indicator, so changes on subfolders aren't tracked.

Can be a good idea to manage exceptions (as new feature) for drive Source control in tracking changes, ie. disabling a .gitignore or manually adding specific folders?

Edit

Example without git on root folder:

[image: There are two sub-folders, one with 5 changes and one wit one]

There are two sub-folders, one with 5 changes and one wit one.

Edit 2

I "deleted" the .git folder and .gitignore on the root, updated the Source code and the changes appears (like in the image above).

I restored the .git folder and .gitignore on the root and the two folders mantains changes tracking but new chanches in other folders aren't tracked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

`.gitignore`

```
# ignore 'TempDir' subfolders
TempDir/*

# exclude a subfolder:
!TempDir/TempSubfolder/

# ignore 'TempSubfolder' subfolders
TempDir/TempSubfolder/*

# exclude a subfolder
!TempDir/TempSubfolder/anotherSubfolder
```

Comment: If I correctly understand, in this way I have all the changes of the folders reported on the git of the root (speaking of VSC-SC), instead I want the changes to be highlighted for each folder, as if there were no .gitignore in the root.

Comment: @mYmage I actually don't understand what you say; Don't you mean exclude some folders from being tracked by git? As you said: `Can be a good idea to manage exceptions (as new feature) for drive Source control in tracking changes, ie. disabling a .gitignore or manually adding specific folders?`

Comment: I try to clarify. In VSC, when you have multiple folders with its own git, Source control displays any changes (the number of files modified) for each folder (see Edit image). If there is a git in the root with relative .gitignore that excludes the folders, the modifications of the sub-folders are not highlighted.

Comment: @mYmage Yes, modifications on folders ignored in .gitignore are not highlighted, because they're not being tracked. So you can do the following: Don't ignore the folder, just ignore all it's subfolders, then exclude those folders which you want their modification be tracked by git and vscode. This way modifications on excluded folders will be shown on Source control panel on vscode.